React.js with rxjs - subscribing inside the store file "fixes" the app
I'm trying out react.js with rxjs. I have build a simple Game Of Life implementation with the option to "bomb" the elements. If I subscribe to my state Observable in the React component, nothing happens. If I additionally subscribe in the data store, the whole thing starts to move.
Component:
import styles from './GOLGrid.module.css';
import { GOLState, useGOLContext } from '../../../../../../store/GOLStore';
import { useObservable } from 'rxjs-hooks';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export function GOLGrid() {
  const context = useGOLContext()
  const state = useObservable(() => context.GOLState$);
  // const [state, setState] = useState<GOLState>();

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   const subscription = context.GOLState$.subscribe({
  //     next: (state) => setState(state),
  //     error: (err) => console.error('Error:', err),
  //     complete: () => console.log('Complete'),
  // });
  //   return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
  // },[]);

  const buildElements = () => {
    return state?.alife.map(
      (alife, i) => <div key={i} className={`${styles.golElement} ${alife ? styles.golElementLiving : ''}`}/>);
  }

  return <div 
  className={styles.GOLGrid} 
  style={{
    gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(${state?.columns ?? 0},auto)`, 
    gridTemplateRows: `repeat(${state?.rows ?? 0},auto)`}}>
    {buildElements()}
  </div>;
}

Store:
import { createContext } from 'react';
import React from 'react';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, combineLatest, filter, interval, map, merge, switchMap, tap, } from 'rxjs';
import { bomb, createStartConfig, newGeneration } from '../services/GOLService';

export type GOLState = {
  rows: number,
  columns: number,
  alife: Array<boolean>,
}

const numberOfRows$ = new BehaviorSubject(8);
const numberOfColumns$ = new BehaviorSubject(8);
const delay$ = new BehaviorSubject(1000);

const bombs$ = new BehaviorSubject<number | null>(null)
const GOLStateLatest$ = new BehaviorSubject<GOLState>({
        rows: numberOfRows$.value,
        columns: numberOfColumns$.value,
        alife: createStartConfig(numberOfRows$.value, numberOfColumns$.value),
    });

const bombed$ = bombs$.pipe(
    filter((e) => e !== null),
    map((e) => bomb(GOLStateLatest$.value!, e!)),
);

const newGeneration$ = delay$.pipe(
    switchMap((e) => interval(e).pipe(
        map(() => newGeneration(GOLStateLatest$.value)),
    ))
)

const GOLState$ = merge(bombed$, newGeneration$).pipe(
    tap((e) => GOLStateLatest$.next(e)),
);

// Just add this and it starts to work!
GOLState$.subscribe({
    next: (state) => null,
    error: (err) => console.error('Error:', err),
    complete: () => console.log('Complete'),
  });
  

type GOLContent = {
    GOLState$: Observable<GOLState>,
}

const GOLContext = createContext<GOLContent>({
    GOLState$: GOLState$,
})

export const useGOLContext = () => React.useContext(GOLContext);

type Props = {
    children?: React.ReactNode
};
export const GOLProvider: React.FC<Props> = ({children}) => (
    <GOLContext.Provider
    value={{
        GOLState$: GOLStateLatest$,
    }}
    >
        {children}
    </GOLContext.Provider>
)

Only change under the comment "Just add this and it starts to work!".
Any explanations?

Okay, got it.
    <GOLContext.Provider
    value={{
        GOLState$: GOLStateLatest$,
    }}
    >
        {children}
    </GOLContext.Provider>

should be
    <GOLContext.Provider
    value={{
        GOLState$: GOLState$,
    }}
    >
        {children}
    </GOLContext.Provider>

